# Magento AddAttributeToFilter not being applied

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to filter a magento product collection by a multiselect attribute with the following...

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToFilter('sparex_makemodel',
    array('in' => $set
    )
 )
 ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

However when I echo out the query it is not being applied? anybody got a clue why? I'm sure this was working earlier... driving me mad now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Matthew, you should check attribute option '`Used in Product Listing`' is set to `'Yes'`.

Comment: I had just come back on to say I had solved it, and saw you had posted this... which is exactly the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
->addAttributeToFilter('sparex_makemodel', array('in'=>$set));
foreach($products as $product)
{
    var_dump($product);
}
```

Comment: Produces the same result, the filter isn't being applied.

Comment: show me your set array and  what is the expected and your current ouptut.